# React Native - Can't read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I press the create button on the GameScreen screen, I get the error Cannot read property 'addRoomPost' of undefined. I don't think I have any import errors, where do you think my mistake is?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
    
const RoomContext = React.createContext();
export const RoomProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [roomPosts, setRoomPosts] = useState([]);

  const addRoomPost = (title, content) => {
    setRoomPosts([
      ...roomPosts,
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999),
        title: title,
        content: content, // You can set a default value or make it dynamic based on user input
      },
    ]);
  };

  const removeRoomPost = (updatedRooms) => {
    setRoomPosts(updatedRooms);
  };

  return (
    <RoomContext.Provider
      value={{
        data: roomPosts,
        addRoomPost,
        removeRoomPost,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </RoomContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default RoomContext;
```

It is my RoomContext.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import GameDetails from "./Components/GameDetail";

const GameScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("CS2");
          navigation.navigate("Create");
        }}
      >
        <GameDetails title="CS2" imageSource={require("../assets/cs2.jpg")} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("LOL ");
          navigation.navigate("Create");
        }}
      >
        <GameDetails title="LOL" imageSource={require("../assets/lol.jpg")} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("Valorant");
          navigation.navigate("Create");
        }}
      >
        <GameDetails
          title="Valorant"
          imageSource={require("../assets/valo.jpeg")}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default GameScreen;
```

It is my GameScreen.js file.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import RoomContext from "./RoomContext";

export const CreateRoom = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { addRoomPost } = useContext(RoomContext); // Accessing addRoomPost from RoomContext
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  const handleCreateRoom = () => {
    console.log("Room created! Navigating to RoomIndexScreen...");
    navigation.navigate("Index");
    addRoomPost(title, content); // Pass title and content to addRoomPost
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Oyun İsmi:</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={title}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)}
        placeholder="Enter Game Name"
        placeholderTextColor="#87CEEB" // Light blue text color
      />
      <Text style={styles.label}>Lig:</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={content}
        onChangeText={(text) => setContent(text)}
        placeholder="Enter League"
        placeholderTextColor="#87CEEB" // Light blue text color
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.lightBlueButton}
        onPress={handleCreateRoom}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Create</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#F0F8FF", // Light blue background
  },
  input: {
    fontSize: 18,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#A9A9A9",
    marginBottom: 15,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: "#87CEEB", // Light blue text color
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 5,
    color: "#333",
  },
  lightBlueButton: {
    backgroundColor: "#4682B4", // Light blue color for the button
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 20, // Adjusted for a different button shape
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default CreateRoom;
```

It is my CreatRoom.js file.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import HomeScreen from "./Screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./Screens/LoginScreen";
import GameScreen from "./Screens/GameScreen";
import CreateRoom from "./Screens/CreatRoom";
import RoomContext from "./Screens/RoomContext";
import RoomIndexScreen from "./Screens/RoomIndexScreen";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Game" component={GameScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create" component={CreateRoom} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Context" component={RoomContext} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Index" component={RoomIndexScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

And it is my app.js file.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import RoomContext from "./RoomContext";
import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { EvilIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const RoomIndexScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { data, addRoomPost, removeRoomPost } = useContext(RoomContext);

  const handleDeleteRoom = (id) => {
    // Remove the room with the specified id
    const updatedRooms = data.filter((room) => room.id !== id);
    removeRoomPost(updatedRooms);
  };

  const handleRoomPress = (id, title) => {
   
    navigation.navigate("Show", { id, title });
 
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(roomPosts) => roomPosts.title}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => handleRoomPress(item.id, item.title)}
            >
              <View style={styles.row}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                  {item.title} - {item.content}
                </Text>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleDeleteRoom(item.id)}>
                    <Feather style={styles.icon} name="trash" size={30} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>
                      navigation.navigate("Edit", {
                        id: item.id,
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    <EvilIcons name="pencil" size={40} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: 30,
    marginLeft: 30, 
  },
});

export default RoomIndexScreen;
```

Comment: Where do you use RoomProvider?

Comment: I edited the codes I use on the RoomIndexScreen screen and added these codes. @JBaczuk

Comment: you're not showing usage of RoomProvider. You should wrap your components in that component first

Comment: Could you show me how can I do ? @gear4